# How to speak about new law which today are real?

Tags: phrases

The context about new political law. 
From my language it's verbatim translated as:

> The law came into force

But I have doubts, is this correct?
How to right to speak it in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. [*Come into force*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_into_force) is a common phrase used to describe this situation, when a law starts being applied:

> To become valid or active (of a law, regulation etc.).

You can also use [*come into effect*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_into_effect).

I'm assuming that by "new political law", you mean that the law is now being enforced. If by new you mean that it has been created (written), you can use "*the law has been [drafted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draft)*".

Answer (score 2):

People will often use the term **effect/effective** when describing the date any law applies.

> The new Jaywalking law, which takes effect this Thursday, will increase the fine to $10,000.
>
> Effective November 30, the rewritten Jaywalking law will reduce the fine to $10.